# How to give all users with a certain discord status a role

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I have a Discord server where I want my bot to give everyone with the status discord.gg/chilling a specific role!

It'll also keep checking ever minute or so and see if a user has got that status or has removed it!

Here's what I have so far...

```
@client.command()
async def rolev(ctx):
    role_added = 0
    role_removed = 0
    memcount = 0
    guild = client.get_guild(763626880775225384)
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="I Am Sexier")
    for member in guild.members:
        if member.activity is None:
            pass
        elif 'discord.gg/chilling' == member.activity.name:
            await member.add_roles(role)
            role_added +=1
        else:
            await member.remove_roles(role)
            role_removed += 1
        memcount += 1
    await ctx.send(f"**Done -> Added The Role For: `{role_added}` | Removed The Role From -> `{role_removed}` | Checked -> `{memcount}`**")
```

And Here's The Error I Get:

```
await member.remove_roles(role)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 685, in remove_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

What can I do?

IK yall are a bunch of geniuses so I hope I get the answer from here...

Comment: `discord.utils.get(client.guilds, name="TOG")` is returning back as None, are you sure your bot is in the TOG guild?

Comment: I recommend using [get_guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_guild#discord.Client.get_guild) by ID instead of searching by name

Comment: @derw imma update the code here please check

Comment: @Cloud i saw you joined the server, could you join and help me again?

Comment: @TOG6 the error you get probably ISN'T about the guild, but about the role.
Can't you just try printing guild and role variables and see if they're None?

Comment: Now you're role is returning none, I would recommend using [guild.get_role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_role#discord.Guild.get_role)

Comment: @derw I can guarantee both are right, I'll anyways switch to guild.get_role

Comment: @DanielVip3 my role seems to be just fine

Comment: By anychance can either of you join my server and help?

Comment: Is the code in your post up to date? Also can you add the full stack trace, not just the bit?

Comment: @derw let me apologize really, I didn't realize I got the message id and not the role Id like a moron, like 5 times in a row, I really wanna apologize sincerely, tho my code is still a bit flawed if youd wanna help the vanity is chilling

Comment: You cant check it because you used it as command, if you have to check in every certain time you should use a non-stoping function like `on_ready(): while True` . you can check status by `member.raw_status()` it will return you a string then you can add check in your code.